# gulp - chaining several gulp.src-gulp.dest expressions in one task?

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp task that contains typical expressions of src-pipe-dest, similar to default example of gulp:

```
 gulp.src('client/templates/*.jade')
      .pipe(jade())
      .pipe(minify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/minified_templates'));
```

and if I want some other task to start after this one, I use "return" of the abovementioned expression to indicate upstream task when the sequence is done.

However, what can I do if my task requires several such expressions, and I want gulp to continue after **all of them** are done? (I use run-sequence for the set of many gulp tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Gulp's dependencies](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps).

Suppose your tasks are named `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`. Now suppose the first three need to be done before `four` is being started. Furthermore, the first three are allowed to run in parallel. This would result in the following definition for task `four`:

```
gulp.task('four', ['one', 'two', 'three'], function() {
    // Your task `four` code here
});
```

This way, you only need to make sure the first three tasks return the correct objects so Gulp knows when they are done. When your run task `four` in this case, it will automatically start the first three tasks and wait for them to complete before running.